# Laravel Storage is not able to locate file in Windows

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6, laravel-8

I am developing a package on Windows which publishes the package.php file in config directory of Laravel.

To get contents of package.php I am using Storage Facade. (I know I can use config() to read it but my usecase is different.)

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
$contents = Storage::get(config_path('package.php'));
```

The above code is throwing FileNotFoundException *but I have checked that the file is present there and I am also able to access it using config() helper.*

```
File not found at path: C:/xampp/htdocs/blog/config/package.php
```

Interestingly when I print the config_path('package.php') it returns

```
"C:\xampp\htdocs\blog\config\package.php"
```

> Notice that the direction of slashes is different in the path shown in
> Exception message and the path returned by config_path() helper.

I work mostly on Linux and hence not have much idea about Windows so I am not able to understand what;s going on here.

Please help!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`Storage::get()` will look only inside the `root` location configured for the disk.
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#retrieving-files

You can use File facade instead of Storage.

```
File::get(config_path('package.php'));
```